# React-navigation drawer is routing me back to previous screen immediately after rendering item screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-drawer

**I have a StackNavigation like this:**

```
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({

Login: {
    screen: Login,
    navigationOptions: () => ({
        title: 'Login',
        headerTintColor: 'white',
        headerStyle:{
            backgroundColor: '#000',
            elevation: 0,
            showdowOpacity: 0
        },
    })
},

Home: {
    screen: AppDrawerNavigator,
    navigationOptions: () => ({
        header: null
    })
},
});
```

**With a DrawerNavigator nested inside:**

```
const AppDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({

Home: {
    screen: Home,
    navigationOptions: {
        drawerLabel: 'Home',
        gesturesEnabled: false,
    }
},

Favorites: {
    screen: Favorites,
    navigationOptions: {
        drawerLabel: 'Favorites',

    }
}

},
{
    drawerPosition: 'left',
    contentComponent: props => <Drawer {...props} />
});
```

The initial route of the stack navigator is working fine

> Login -> Home

But when I try navigating from Home to Favorites it navigates immediately back to Home after rendering the Favorites screen.

I am using react-navigation@2.11.2 and react-native@0.56.0

Comment: try renaming the Home in root stack and Home in drawer stack .. may be they are messing up

Comment: Can you please tell the use case of why you are using a DrawerNavigator. Are you trying to use a hamburger menu in your Home page (which uses stack navigator to goto other pages)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Home being used in both stack and drawer navigator.
There are high chances of name conflicts occurring here.

Try this structure.

```
const Stack = {
    FirstView: {
        screen: FirstView
    },
    SecondView: {
        screen: SecondView
    },
    ThirdView: {
        screen: ThirdView
    }
};

const DrawerRoutes = {
    FirstViewStack: {
        name: 'FirstViewStack',
        screen: StackNavigator(Stack, { initialRouteName: 'FirstView' })
    },
    SecondViewStack: {
        name: 'SecondViewStack',
        screen: StackNavigator(Stack, { initialRouteName: 'SecondView' })
    },
    ThirdViewStack: {
        name: 'ThirdViewStack',
        screen: StackNavigator(Stack, { initialRouteName: 'ThirdView' })
    },
};

const RootNavigator =
    StackNavigator({
        Drawer: {
            name: 'Drawer',
            screen: DrawerNavigator(
                DrawerRoutes,
            ),
        },
        ...Stack
    },
        {
            headerMode: 'none'
        }
    );
```

I faced a similar issue when i tried to use a hamburger menu in my Home page (which uses stack navigator to goto other pages).

Check this [Git Article](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/131) also.